# What should be the primary key?

Tags: mysql

I have first name, last name, mobile number, graduation and entry date are the fields of table. I'm unable to understand which one should be my primary key?

Comment: Mobile Number can be but that's not the best way to do it. Create an extra field and name it `id`, that will be your primary field.

Comment: None of the above

Comment: Follow the standard and have a column "id" as a primary key. its always better to have id column as a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use another column like `id` as a pk.

Comment: Careful, because using phone number as a primary key means that it will never be an optional field. I think it's better to create an `id` field because it won't be linked to any business logic.

Comment: @ThomasKint Yes that's why I have first suggest to set the user `id`. :)

Comment: @Strawberry If it's a terrible idea then please share you idea in answer. We'll learn new things. :)